# how to get a list of methods from a class in java?

Tags: java, refactoring

I want to enter the path of the java class as input and in output it should give me the list of methods in that class.how do i proceed ? can anyone guide me.pls.

Comment: there are already lot of similar question, you should have made a search first.

Comment: What you are describing isn't refactoring (which is to rewrite code in order to increase performance/readability without changing behaviour). IDEs like eclipse have views that show you all the attributes and methods of the class you have open...

Comment: Please demonstrate what work you have done with this already.  What research?

Answer (score 1):

```
Class personClass = Person.class;

//Get the methods
Method[] methods = personClass.getDeclaredMethods();

//Loop through the methods and print out their names
for (Method method : methods)
{
    System.out.println(method.getName());
}
```

Comment: What if i have to read the methods from the java class from my system's local path? Is it possible to directly read it or i will have to load that file in any package and do that?

Comment: You can do it on any class.  It has nothing to do with packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java Reflection API  - To find out about how to use it go through  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classMembers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can give the path name in double quotation and get the java class.From the java class you can get array of methods, and by iteration over the array of methods you can name of the methods by its `.getName()` method, and it can be converted to list.

```
Class class = Class.forName("com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.facade."
                    + className);
    Method[] mymethods = class.getMethods();
```

let me know if it works or not

Thanks, 
Punam

Comment: What if i have to read the methods from the java class from my system's local path?
Is it possible to directly read it or i will have to load that file in any package and do that?

Comment: @avadha you can get the path using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` and then you need to convert the path separator and you can get class written anywhere in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically using reflection API (`obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`) or using command line utility `javap` that is a part of your JDK distribution.